# aws ssm command increase execution timeout not delevery timeout

Tags: aws-ssm

I Need to increase aws ssm send command execution timeout , not delivery time out.

I use below command but it is increasing delivery time out.

aws ssm send-command --region us-east-1 --instance-ids "i-0704d84255e03g4545"  --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters "commands='python3 /root/dba/timeout.py'" --timeout-seconds 172880

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDZLO.png)

Thanks
Siddartha

Answer (score 0):

Here are a way to increase the effective timeout for SSM command execution:

`Use the MaxConcurrency and MaxErrors Parameters:`
When you create an SSM document or run a command using the AWS Management Console or AWS CLI, you can set the MaxConcurrency and MaxErrors parameters. By adjusting these values, you can control how many instances run the command concurrently and how many errors are tolerated before failing the execution. This indirectly affects the overall execution time.

For example, if you set `MaxConcurrency to 50 and MaxErrors to 10`, it means that 50 instances will execute the command concurrently, and if 10 or more of them encounter errors, the execution will fail. You can fine-tune these values to suit your needs.